# C# Label doesnt update on timer

Tags: c#, label

I have a function on my web page to which I pass a message. The function changes a label to to the message but after 3 seconds I want the label to hide or have assigned a "" value. In the console, the text value changes but in the web page 
it remains the same.

```
private void notify(string msg)
{
    notification.Text = msg;

    System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer((obj) =>
    {
        bar();
        timer.Dispose();
    },
    null, 3000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

}

private void bar()
{
    notification.Text="";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(notification.Text); //Output ""
}
```

Comment: Is this for WebForms? Your notification.Text isn't changing because the page has already been painted by the time that function fires off via the System.Threading.Timer.

Look into using setTimeout on the client side and change this value after the 3000 milis via Javascript.  If you're using jQuery, you can fire this off on document.ready something like this: 

$(function() { setTimeout(function() { $('#notification').val(''); }), 3000); });

Comment: Are you expecting the timer to run **after** the web page has been served to the client?

Comment: Yes i want the timer to run after the web page has been served to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about it,
You will have to use **setInterval(func,3000)** on client side using javascript.In such a sense when Notify will be called then after 3000 seconds on client side hide to the Label.Use following code

**Design File(.aspx)**

```
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function Hide()
            {
                document.getElementById("notification").hidden = true;
            }
            setInterval(Hide, 3000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="notification" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Code File(.cs)** when it's calling notify method on server side.I'm calling over the Page_Load,It will be your own choice.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notify("ok");
}
private void notify(string msg)
{
    notification.Text = msg;
}
```